# Python - Get dictionary element in a list of dictionaries after an if statement

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I get a dictionary value in a list of dictionaries, based on the dictionary satisfying some condition? For instance, if one of the dictionaries in the list has the id=5, I want to print the value corresponding to the `name` key of that dictionary:

```
list = [{'name': 'Mike', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'Ellen', 'id': 5}]
id = 5
if any(m['id'] == id for m in list):
    print m['name']
```

This won't work because `m` is not defined outside the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *list* of dictionaries, so you can use a list comprehension:

```
[d for d in lst if d['id'] == 5]

# [{'id': 5, 'name': 'Ellen'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new_list = [m['name'] for m in list if m['id']==5]
print '\n'.join(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be easy to accomplish with a single for-loop:

```
for d in list:
    if 'id' in d and d['in'] == 5:
        print(d['name'])
```

There are two key concepts to learn here. The first is that we used a [for loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) to "go through each element of the list". The second, is that we used the [in](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) word to check if a dictionary had a certain key.

Comment: Since this can be handled with a fairly basic list comprehension, I would guess that is "Pythonic" way to solve his problem, as opposed to explicitly writing a loop.

Comment: @Aaron I doubt just printing out the name is the goal.  If we assume that some more complicated logic is needed at this point, a list comprehension may not be useful. (And the OP does not seem to understand how to use dictionaries, so I think this is a bad time to explain list comprehensions.)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
for entry in list:
    if entry['id']==5:
        print entry['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist in `Python2`, but a simple solution in `Python3` would be to use a `ChainMap` instead of a `list`.

```
import collections

d = collections.ChainMap(*[{'name':'Mike', 'id': 1}, {'name':'Ellen', 'id': 5}])
if 'id' in d:
    print(d['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the filter function:

```
lis = [ {'name': 'Mike', 'id': 1}, {'name':'Ellen', 'id': 5}]
result = filter(lambda dic:dic['id']==5,lis)[0]['name']
print(result)
```